# WHO report into COVID pandemic origins

Tags: pronunciation

Is WHO, which stands for World Health Organization, always pronounced as  /ˈdʌb·əl·ju/eɪtʃ/əʊ/?

> **WHO report into COVID pandemic origins** zeroes in on animal markets, not labs
> Scientists say the conclusions make sense but note that supporters of the lab-leak theory are unlikely to be satisfied.

> Source:  [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00865-8)

Comment: If you look in a dictionary, like the C.E.D. you will find that pronunciation of the word World varies between The UK and The US.

Comment: In fact CED list the variance in pronunciation of the "O" - O, noun [ C or U ] UK  /əʊ/ US  /oʊ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The World Health Organisation, abbreviated WHO, is usually and correctly read as W. H. O. in three letters. It is non-standard or incorrect to read it as an acronym "who" or /hu:/.

In contrast, "COVID" is always read as an acronym /kəʊvɪd/, It is not an initialism but instead is from as COrona VIrus Disease.

There is no "rule" that can decide if an abbreviation is read as letters or a word, you just have to follow what other people do.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid using ‘always’ in a question about English pronunciation because pronunciation of a particular word varies enormously from accent to accent/ person to person.

Also note that **/phonemes/** can be **[realised in many different ways]**

- **W:** it can either be [ˈdʌbljuː] or [ˈdʌbəlˌjuː]
- **H:** The letter *H* is pronounced in different ways in different accents of English: it can either be [heɪt͡ʃ] or [eɪt͡ʃ]
- **O:** In BrE, it's /əʊ/, in AmE it's /oʊ/, in AuE it's something like /əʉ/

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  Many English-speaking regions pronounce the letters differently, particularly the "H".